# Cannot update nodejs to newer version

Tags: software-installation, nodejs

Trying to install a newer version of nodejs but the same version keeps installing for some reason. Here's my flow:

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs*
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

After v0.10.25 is still installed, can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does the second command executed do anything strange? It worked fine for me.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I was able to install the new version using npm instead of the repo I listed in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install the newest version of node through node package manager (npm).

Answer (score -2):

When you do that command you also install *NODEJS Legacy* which is the older version.

```
apt search nodejs
apt-get install nodejs
```

You'll get a list of NodeJS packages with a short description and the newer Node package.